# How to generate JSON from list of JSONs in Grails

Tags: json, list, grails, join

I have got the following code:

```
package xxx

import javax.ws.rs.Path
import javax.ws.rs.GET
import javax.ws.rs.Produces
import grails.converters.JSON
import org.json.simple.JSONObject


@Path('/api/machine')
class MachineService {

    @GET
    @Produces(['application/json'])
    def String readAll() {
        def List<Machine> z = new ArrayList<Machine>(Machine.findAll())
        def List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()

        for (i in z) {
            list.add([id: i.getId(), name: i.getName()] as JSON).toString()
        }


    }
}
```

I would like to join **list** into one JSON and return it. Could you show me any code samples?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can accomplish this in one line:

```
Machine.all.collect{ [id: it.id, name: it.name] } as JSON
```

Comment: but I want to create one JSON fro list of JSONS

Comment: @Alex It does exactly that. What is `Machine`?

Answer (score 0):

@James Kleeh's answer returns a JSON array which is a valid JSON and should suffice your purpose. If you need a JSONObject (named Array) then you can enhance James answer by using like:

`[machineList: Machine.all.collect{ [id: it.id, name: it.name] }] as JSON`

I guess when you mean a JSON with list of JSONs is nothing but a JSON array or a JSON Object with a JSON Array. Both of the approaches work, but James answer is the optimized approach.